# GCM notification when Google Drive is updated?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I have an Android app that stores user specific data to the users Google Drive account so it can be synced across multiple devices. This works great except for when one device uploads changes and another has yet to check for changes. I would like to hook in Google Cloud Messaging to send a message down to notify other devices that they should pull in the new data. Now this would be easy if I was managing a backend server but I don't have access to the Drive services to include this. Is there any way to accomplish this currently?

Comment: Every time the user uploads just post to the server and trigger an event! This event will send a new notification that will trigger a pending intent on the devices and then the devices will retrieve the new data from server!

Comment: Could you clarify? The device that uploads to Drive will not be able to communicate with the other devices, how would I tell Drive to send an event down to other devices?

Comment: You will make a POST request and trigger an event receiver on the server! Then the server will communicate with the other dedvices and tell them that there is an update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push notifications via webhook are currently being worked on. If you would like access, you should apply for the [Google Drive Early Access Program](https://developers.google.com/drive/earlyaccess).

Initially, only notifications to a web server via POST are supported but you could use that to proxy Android notifications. Later, it is expected that 1st party Android notifications will be supported.

Comment: Alright thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Too bad it's not ready but I'll keep an eye out.